# Stream exception & System.Xml.XmlException: '--' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ''

Tags: c#, xml, streamwriter

I am getting error thrown by StreamWriter, the message I am getting is:

```
Length = '(sw.BaseStream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
Position = '(sw.BaseStream).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

The Stack Trace:

```
Message: System.Xml.XmlException: '6163592' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '\'" or "".
Stack Trace: System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(String expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(Stream inStream)
   at BasecampManager.SendRequest(String command, String request) in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\basecamp\Basecamp_Net_20_API_src\BasecampAPI\BasecampManager.cs:line 146
```

My code:

```
public XmlDocument SendRequest(string command, string request) 
{
    XmlDocument result = null;
    if (IsInitialized()) 
    {
        result = new XmlDocument();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = null;

        try 
        {
            string prefix = (m_SecureMode) ? "https://" : "http://";
            string url = string.Concat(prefix, m_Url, command);
            webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

            string UsernameAndPassword = string.Concat(m_Username, ":", m_Password);
            string EncryptedDetails = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UsernameAndPassword));
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + EncryptedDetails);

            //MessageBox.Show(webRequest.GetRequestStream().ToString());

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
               sw.WriteLine(request);
            }

            // Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.

            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result.Load(sr.BaseStream);
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            string ErrorXml = string.Format("<error>{0}</error>", ex.ToString());
            result.LoadXml(ErrorXml);
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (webRequest != null)
                webRequest.GetRequestStream().Close();

            if (webResponse != null)
                webResponse.GetResponseStream().Close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am not sure what is the problem. I have checked many post but nothing helps me really.

This code was working perfectly fine couple of months ago. Now it stopped working automatically and through the exception. By thinking it may be some issue with VS 2005 I have tried running this code on VS 2005, 2008, 2010 but it did not work any more.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely server response is no longer valid XML.

Use some HTTP debugging tool (i.e. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) ) to see how response actually look like. Or save response as text instead of trying to load as XML.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggested improvements for your code:

```
public XmlDocument SendRequest(string command, string request)
{
    if (!IsInitialized())
        return null;

    var result = new XmlDocument();

    try
    {
        var prefix = (m_SecureMode) ? "https://" : "http://";
        var url = string.Concat(prefix, m_Url, command);
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

        var UsernameAndPassword = string.Concat(m_Username, ":", m_Password);
        var EncryptedDetails = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UsernameAndPassword));
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + EncryptedDetails);

        using (var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(request);
            }
        }

        using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                result.Load(responseStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.LoadXml("<error></error>");
        result.DocumentElement.InnerText = ex.ToString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

All of the objects you create that implement IDisposable should be in a `using` block. You had omitted the `WebResponse` and the result `Stream`.

Also, `XmlDocument.Load` can accept a `Stream` directly, so there was no need to use in intermediate `StreamReader`.
I would further suggest removing the try/catch block entirely, and not forcing your callers to have to read the XML to determine whether an error occurred. However, if you insist on doing that, then you should at least use an XML API to build your XML. You have no idea what's inside of `ex.ToString()`, so it's quite possible that throwing that into the middle of `<error>{0}</error>` would produce invalid XML.